# What are different steps to optimize the postgres database and queries?

Tags: ruby, database, postgresql, query-optimization

I am optimizing Postgres with Ruby on Rails. For last few days I am finding that my site is loading slowly. Application is using different queries with join of 3-4 tables to fetch the data.

Could you help me what I need to do to improve the performance of the application at database level?

Comment: Your question is quite generic, so I wouldn't hope for really helpful answers. Personally I got a lot from reading the two books "Enterprise Rails" and "PostgreSQL 9.0 High Performance".

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here.  You need to capture and look at all the activity and go from there. The link below provides a open source tool to do that.

http://dalibo.github.io/pgbadger/